# HTML Select Menu - modify Javascript variable on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a Javascript that stores a variable for a default phone number, but I would like users to be able to override this based on the options in a select menu. If they make a selection from the menu I would like the Javascript variable to be updated with the new value from the selected option.

Here's the script:

```js
$("#callContact1").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.server.com/callback.php?recipientNumber=0412345678&type=makecall",
      data: {},
      type: "GET"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(data).show();
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus;
      console.log('ajaxError: ' + ajaxError);
      //make alert visible 
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(ajaxError).show();
    })
})
```

I would like to edit the value of the 'recipientNumber=0412345678' in the url of the AJAX request function whenever this select menu is changed:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="callBackNumber" id="callBackNumber">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0418468103" selected>Mobile (0412345678)</option>
<option value="0294846565">Work (0299887766)</option>
<option value="0233445566">Home (0233445566)</option>            
</select>
```

I'm not sure if this is possible or if there is a better way to construct this to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global variable with your **defaultPhoneNumber**.

```
var defaultPhoneNumber = $("#callBackNumber").val();
```

Update that variable on change of dropdownlist.

```
$("#callBackNumber").change(function(){
  defaultPhoneNumber  = $(this).val();
});
```

And use updated value in URL

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.server.com/callback.php?recipientNumber="+ defaultPhoneNumber  +"&type=makecall",
      data: {},
      type: "GET"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#callBackNumber").on("change", function() {` and pass the `this.value` number

```js
$("#callBackNumber").on("change", function() {

  var number = this.value;

  if(!number) {
    return console.log("Please select a number!"); // 
  }

  // Now let's use that number
  $.ajax({ 
      url: "https://www.server.com/callback.php?recipientNumber="+ number +"&type=makecall",
      data: {},
      type: "GET"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(data).show();
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus;
      console.log('ajaxError: ' + ajaxError);
      //make alert visible 
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(ajaxError).show();
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" name="callBackNumber" id="callBackNumber">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0418468103" selected>Mobile (0412345678)</option>
<option value="0294846565">Work (0299887766)</option>
<option value="0233445566">Home (0233445566)</option>            
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible, and You have done something similar ;)

select element support's `change` event, which fires after selecting option from dropdown.

```
$('#callBackNumber').on('change', (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value

  fireCallback(value)
})
```

ofc You have to write `fireCallback` function, which will do the thing

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
var phoneNum = "0412345678";
$("#callBackNumber").change(function() {
  phoneNum = $(this).val();
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hzxt45ad/)

Create a global variable, always concatenate it in the ajax URL. Update the value of the variable whenever the dropdown is changed. You will always have latest value in your variable and hence in your ajax URL.